# Issue with Swift iOS pod framework integration in Unity 3D

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm hoping you can help out a fellow Unity developer.
I've created a Podspec repository on Github and generated an iOS native framework using Cocoapod dependencies, which I intend to use in my Unity project. The podspec is as follows:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

    s.name             = 'Mikros'
    s.version          = '1.0.0'
    s.summary          = 'Library to interact with Mikros API.'
    s.swift_version    = '5'
    s.description      = 'Contains interfaces that assist in interacting with the Mikros API.'
    s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/TATUMGAMES/TG-MIKROS-FRAMEWORK-ios'
    s.source           = { :git => 'git@github.com:TATUMGAMES/TG-MIKROS-FRAMEWORK-ios.git', :tag => s.version }
    s.author           = { 'Tatum Games' => 'support@tatumgames.com' }
    s.ios.deployment_target  = '12.0'

    s.source_files = 'mikros-framework-ios/**/*.{h,swift}'
    s.resources = "mikros-framework-ios/**/*.{xcdatamodeld}"
    s.license = { :type => 'TBD', :file => 'LICENSE' }
end
```

I'm referencing this podspec from Unity as directed for [External Dependency Manager](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver):

```
<dependencies>
 <iosPods>
  <iosPod name="Mikros" version="~> 1.0.0" bitcodeEnabled="true" minTargetSdk="7.0" addToAllTargets="false">
   <sources>
    <source>https://github.com/TATUMGAMES/TG-MIKROS-FRAMEWORK-POD-ios.git</source>
   </sources>
  </iosPod>
 </iosPods>
</dependencies>
```

But I get the following error on build:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `Mikros (~> 1.0.0)`
```

I'm following [this](https://medium.com/voodoo-engineering/bringing-native-ios-frameworks-into-unity-games-by-hacking-ios-methods-2c656d18cf9b) Medium tutorial.

This iOS framework of mine is written in Swift and I'm also struggling with how to call functions of this framework from Unity.

Can you please help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question. Has anyone done this before? I am also looking for examples of creating a bridge between native Swift and Unity.